# Android WebRTC - create 1-N calls

Tags: android, webrtc

I have a project https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo. This project works 1 -1 calls. I modified the PeerConnectionClient.class:

```
private static final PeerConnectionClient instance = new PeerConnectionClient();
    // private final PCObserver pcObserver = new PCObserver();
    private final PCObserver[] pcObservers = new PCObserver[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
    // private final SDPObserver sdpObserver = new SDPObserver();
    private final SDPObserver[] sdpObservers = new SDPObserver[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
    private final LooperExecutor executor;

    private static final int MAX_CONNECTIONS = 3;

    private PeerConnectionFactory factory;
    private PeerConnection[] peerConnections = new PeerConnection[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
    PeerConnectionFactory.Options options = null;
    private VideoSource videoSource;
    private boolean videoCallEnabled;
    private boolean audioCallEnabled;
    private boolean preferIsac;
    private boolean preferH264;
    private boolean videoSourceStopped;
    private boolean isError;
    private Timer statsTimer;
    private VideoRenderer.Callbacks localRender;   
    private VideoRenderer.Callbacks[] remoteRenders;
    private SignalingParameters signalingParameters;
    private MediaConstraints pcConstraints;
    private MediaConstraints videoConstraints;
    private MediaConstraints audioConstraints;
    private MediaConstraints sdpMediaConstraints;
    private PeerConnectionParameters peerConnectionParameters;
    // Queued remote ICE candidates are consumed only after both local and
    // remote descriptions are set. Similarly local ICE candidates are sent to
    // remote peer after both local and remote description are set.
    private LinkedList<IceCandidate>[] queuedRemoteCandidateLists = new LinkedList[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
    private PeerConnectionEvents events;
    private boolean[] isConnectionInitiator = new boolean[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
    private SessionDescription[] localSdps = new SessionDescription[MAX_CONNECTIONS]; // either offer or answer SDP
    private MediaStream mediaStream;
    private int numberOfCameras;
    private VideoCapturerAndroid videoCapturer;
    // enableVideo is set to true if video should be rendered and sent.
    private boolean renderVideo;
    private VideoTrack localVideoTrack;
    private VideoTrack[] remoteVideoTracks = new VideoTrack[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
```

as here https://pastebin.com/c0YCHS6g. My Activity for call: https://pastebin.com/8RVwVZRq

Answer (score 0):

*Android WebRTC - create `1-N` calls*, **what is the value of `N` here?**

If `N > 4` you need to use a media relay servers(SFU/SVC) servers, otherwise mobile will die !!
For N remote participants, WebRTC will do N times encoding (it will eat CPU & battery N times) and to relay stream to N participants it will consume N times bandwidth (you can't imagine it in 3G/4G).

Choose a media server based on your use case from Janus/Jitsi/Kurento/Licode/red5/switchrtc/wowza and many more.

**If `N <= 4`:**
you need to refactor peerConnectionClinet into two parts.
1. Singleton Factory: Main peerConnectionFactory & MediaStream/MediaTracks
2. PC Instances: create a peerConnection from the Singleton Factory and add the same stream to all the instances. This pc instance is responsible for offer/answer/candidates exchange for each endpoint.